# How to fix TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'e.parentNode')

Tags: javascript, ios, mootools

when I try to send a message to the server I receive an error in the console, please help to solve this problem 
console sand me mootools-core-1.4.5.js

`after: function(l, e) {
            var D = e.parentNode;
            if (D) {
                D.insertBefore(l, e.nextSibling);
            }`

mine code  [here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s448/sh/a1d1bdd9-24be-430c-a06d-5c8c0bf8952b/8b89d559e705c2d2df17f57f5fb498eb)

Comment: Can you explain where this code comes from and what is `e` in that function?

Comment: here mine code https://www.evernote.com/shard/s448/sh/a1d1bdd9-24be-430c-a06d-5c8c0bf8952b/8b89d559e705c2d2df17f57f5fb498eb

Comment: That error is coming from these lines (**[source code](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Element/Element.js#L495-L498)**). And that means that the element is not found in your code where you use `(.inject(element, 'after');`. Can you post your HTML also to understand the problem better?

Comment: of course, but tomorrow, I haven't code my home, I can give html code when I come to work)) Thank you, I'm a novice programmer and many still do not understand

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Saw your code, in the inject part the element passed is incorrect It is carrying double $$ instead of single.

Your Code:

```
  ).inject($$('div.comment').getLast(), 'after');
```

Should be

```
   ).inject($('div.comment').getLast(), 'after');
```

Comment: thanks a lot:)) but I'm get another error: "TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating '$('div.comment').getLast')"

Comment: try $('div.comment').last()

Comment: @V31, `$$` is right. In MooTools the single dollar will not select other elements than by their ID.

Comment: @Sergio: In the code that he had shared he has Jquery selectors and not the mooTools selectors

Comment: @V31 I see `$('textinput1').value` and `$('textinput1').set('value', '');` That is MooTools, meaning `document.getElementById('textinput1').value = '';`